# Refillable rollerball pen without creating wastes

Tags: office-supplies

I am looking to find something like a "sustainable pen". The main idea is to use a rollerball pen (for convenience and ease of use), refillable (to avoid having to throw it away) and avoid using disposable pen refills.

I found some Rollerball pen, refillable with ink that could be use in fountain pens. However, it's not easy to use (the ink stay wet for a little while), so I am pretty sure I will not be able to convert people to use this instead of classic plastic Bic pens.

Is there any way to refill a rollerball pen with a ink that is like "gelly" or any other solution to use a rollerball point and not having to throw away a piece of plastic every time it's empty ?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Are you looking for a refillable pen that exists in the marketplace for your own use, exploring the potential to create one, or asking about the potential to refill an existing pen that is sold as a disposable?  Each paragraph seems to reflect a different one of those questions.

Comment: Either an existing one or a way to refill a disposable. I already looked around and did not find anything and I don't think you guys are a search engine, however I am afraid I missed some keyword or magical websites dedicated to this! What is clear is : I am not looking to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

For a sustainable pen, I'd suggest a fountain pen. There are those with a mechanism wherby they can be refilled directly, or those with a disposable cartridges, which could actually be refilled by a syringe, instead of disposed of. (Take a look at the nature, history and development of the ballpoint pen and the ink used to see why refilling a ballpoint type of cartridge will be rather problematic.)

Comment: Those mechanisms are also available separately: those look like a disposable cartridge with a plunger on the end, so they'll fit any fountain pen made for disposable cartridges.